# Line listener event is lost

Tags: java, audio

I try to play a signal using the Java clip object. I start the clip, then I wait for the STOP event to be fired until I continue the thread. I observed that if I exit the calling thread, which may happen in my application, the sound does not play or only plays the first part.

This works fine most of the time, however, every about 50th time, neither the START nor the STOP event is fired, which causes the current thread to wait forever.

The question now is, did I do something wrong with the synchronisation which make me loose the events?

```
private static volatile boolean isPlaying = false;
private static final Object waitObject = new Object();

public static void playClip(...)

...

    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(...);

    clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
            if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                event.getLine().close();
                synchronized (waitObject) {
                    isPlaying = false;                        
                    waitObject.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    });


    // start playing clip
    synchronized (waitObject) { 
        isPlaying = true;
    }
    clip.start();

    // keep Thread running otherwise the audio output is stopped when caller thread exits
    try {
        while (isPlaying) {
            synchronized (waitObject) {
                waitObject.wait();                    
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the new version using 
`CountDownLatch`:

```
private static volatile CountDownLatch playingFinished = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static void playClip(...)

...
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(...);
    clip.open(audioInputStream);

    // use line listener to take care of synchronous call
    clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
        public void update(LineEvent event) {
            if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                event.getLine().close();
                playingFinished.countDown();
            }
        }
    });

    clip.start();

    try {
        playingFinished.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    playingFinished = new CountDownLatch(1);
```

I didn't include the debugging statements, but they indicate that the thread hangs in `playingFinished.await();` because the STOP event was not fired and `playingFinished.countDown();` is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and rework your code to use the `CountDownLatch` instead of the low-level wait-notify API. Your problem might then evaporate on its own.

```
public void playClip() throws Exception {
  final CountDownLatch playingFinished = new CountDownLatch(1);
  final Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(...);
  clip.open(...);
  clip.addLineListener(new LineListener() {
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
      if (event.getType() == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
        event.getLine().close();
        playingFinished.countDown();
      }
    }
  });
  clip.start();
  try {
    playingFinished.await();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the CoundDownLatch construct instead of the wait/notify, however the problem still remains. It has occurred to me that it seems to depend on the JVM. When I use OpenJDK, the event is lost sometimes, when I use the Java Standard Edition the problem does not occur.

Comment: Please post the changed code. If it's jvm-dependant, it's 99% because you're doing something wrong and just getting lucky when it works.

Comment: I've edited the question and posted the changed code, that now includes the `CoundDownLatch` instead of `wait/notify`

Comment: All I can see is that this code contains a race condition on the `CountDownLatch`. It may or may not cause your problem, but it would still be much better if you did it right. You may indeed be hitting that 1% where the trouble is really within the OpenJDK.

Comment: See code in the updated answer. It probably only has educational value and doesn't help your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on the `CountDownLatch` construction. Unfortunately, as you have guessed, it did not solve the problem. I have now included a timeout in the `await` statement, which is not very elegant but at least prevents the Thread from freezing completely. Just for completeness, I've fixed the missing `static` in the `playClip` method